# Polymer Elements paper-tabs - Error in Polymer 3

Tags: polymer, paper-elements, polymer-3.x

**After install**

npm i @polymer/paper-tabs

**and import :**

import '@polymer/paper-tabs/paper-tab.js';

import '@polymer/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.js';

**Getting error on run :**

polymer-fn.js:43 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': this name has already been used with this registry
    at Polymer (http://localhost:8081/node_modules/@polymer/polymer/lib/legacy/polymer-fn.js:43:18)
    at http://localhost:8081/node_modules/@polymer/paper-tabs/node_modules/@polymer/paper-ripple/paper-ripple.js:314:1

Comment: did not really use Polymer 3, but just based on the error message.. I got a very similar error when the same component was included twice with different relative paths, even if they resolved in the end to the same absolute path..

Comment: Are you using polymer-cli? If yes, have you tried building the project with `polymer build`?

Comment: Yes using polymer-cli and tried build with polymer build and npm run build.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your project directory, try to:

-install paper-tabs, `npm i --save @polymer/paper-tabs`

-remove directory node_modules

-remove file packege-lock.json

-reinstall dependencies via npm, `npm install`

-in my-app.js (see starter-kit) import paper-tabs.js `import '@polymer/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.js';`